Is polynomial not bijective, on this finited field?

Let $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb F_p,p=2^{127}-1$ and $P(x)=x^{16}+ax^{11}+bx^{5}+c$.
Is it true that $P(x)$ not bijective on $\mathbb F_p$?

I have asked this question here (*), but no answer.
(*) : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3337232

What is the motivation for this particular question?

Why this particular prime and this particular shape of a polynomial? Surely you didn't just randomly stumble upon them and randomly guessed that this holds. If there is anything in particular that lead you to these forms, it would be helpful to provide that context. The same applies to your other recent questions.

I think that posing challenge problems like this on MO where you know, but intentionally do not reveal, more information is generally considered bad form.  (Or, at least, I consider it such, especially if you do not reveal the existence of this extra information until asked twice.)

@LSpice Especially given earlier shenanigans of this same type (see also here).

Yes, it is true. If $a\ne 0$, sum up $(x^{16}+ax^{11}+bx^5)^{(p+1)/16+3}$ over $x\in \mathbb{F}_p$. If it was bijective, the sum must be 0, but the coefficient of $x^{p-1}$ (which is only relevant for this sum) is non zero. If $a=0$ but $b\ne 0$, do the same with $(x^{16}+bx^5)^{(p+1)/16+4}$.

I love this idea, but I'm too dense to work it out.  How do you find the coefficient of $x^{p - 1}$?

@LSpice The first polynomial has degree $p+49$, so you might as well look at the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in the reversed polynomial $(1+ax^5+bx^{11})^{(p+1)/16+3}$. Since $50=5n+11m$ ($n,m$ nonnegative integers) implies $m=0$ and $n=10$, the relevant coefficient is the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in $(1+ax^5)^{(p+1)/16+3}$. Now apply the binomial theorem to find that the coefficient is $a^{10}\binom{A}{10}$ where $10<A<p$ which must be nonzero.

@OfirGorodetsky, re, thanks!
